# Oracle PL/SQL- query a table, selecting data from the same table but utilizing an ID from another

Tags: oracle, plsql

I know the title will not do justice, and I have tried searching around between Joins and Merges, however I am a bit stumped and could use some guidance writing this.

I have two tables:

```
 Table 1                
 A  B   C       
 20348  12306   191     
 31502  12306           
 20342  12297   191     
 31492  12297           
 20341  12296   191     
 31504  12296           
 20344  12299   191     
 31499  12299           

Table 2             
A(ident)B (F_Key of T1_A)   C   D   E
25003   20348              1    2   3
35915   20342              1    2   3
41883   20341              1    2   3
31303   20344              1    2   3
```

I want to take table 2, select the contents B, C, D, E, However I want to select Table 1, column A as B where Table 1 C is null Table 1 B = X.

Table 2 Column B is the foreign Key of Table 1 A

As a result, I would like to see this:

```
A       B       C   D   E
5555    31502   1   2   3
5556    31492   1   2   3
5557    31504   1   2   3
5558    31499   1   2   3
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: In the result that you want to see, column A has different values from Table1.A and from Table2.A. Can you explain what do those values represent?

Comment: Table 2a is an identities coulmn. I fictitiously auto incremented A.

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

So if I understood your question correctly, you need case statement in your select:

```
select (case when t1.C is null and t1.b=X then t1.A else t2.B end), t2.C, t2.D, t2.E
 from Table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.A = t2.B
```

Also not sure what `Table 1 B = X` means so I just kept the syntax same as in your explanation. Feel free to modify that part. Give it a try to see whether it works for you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out for what I needed.

I end up going up a further level in my database where I introduced Table 3, where its Primary key was the Foreign Key of Table 1 Column B that referenced a primary key and created:

```
select t1b.A, t2.C, t2.D, t2.E
from Table1 t1a, table1 t1b, table2 t2, table3 t3 
WHERE t3.A = t1a.b
AND t1a.C is null
AND t2.B = t1a.A
AND t1b.B = t3.A
AND t1b.B = 'xxx'
```